# How call a method in java using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a scenario where I instantiate a class and call a method like the one given below using java reflection mechanism.

```
    WorkerObjectType workerObjectType = new WorkerObjectType();
    WorkerObjectIDType workerObjectIdType = new WorkerObjectIDType();
    workerObjectIdType.setType("Employee_ID");
    workerObjectIdType.setValue("102");
    workerObjectType.getID().add(workerObjectIdType);
    workerReqReferenceType.getWorkerReference().add(workerObjectType);
```

For above case I tried using java reflection as below:

```
Class<?> workerObjectTypeRef = Class.forName("platinum.humanresource.WorkerObjectType");
Object workerObjectType = workerObjectTypeRef.newInstance();
Class<?> workerObjectIDTypeRef = Class.forName("platinum.humanresource.WorkerObjectIDType");
Object workerObjectIdType = workerObjectIDTypeRef.newInstance();
Method setType = workerObjectIDTypeRef.getDeclaredMethod("setType", String.class);
setType.invoke(workerObjectIdType, "Employee_ID");
Method setValue = workerObjectIDTypeRef.getDeclaredMethod("setValue", String.class);
setValue.invoke(workerObjectIdType, "102");
```

I am unable to do it particularly in the following scenario:

```
workerObjectType.getID().add(workerObjectIdType);
workerReqReferenceType.getWorkerReference().add(workerObjectType);
```

Comment: I know this is not reflection, I am asking how to use reflection for this case. @flakes

Comment: I have edited the post can you now take a look of it. @flakes

Comment: Better to add also implementation of classes `WorkerObjectType`, `WorkerObjectIDType`. The return type of the `getID()` method is also important. Is that a `java.util.Collection` or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to call the getters for the instances, and then invoke methods on the returned instances using reflection as well. Here's an example for `workerObjectType.getID().add(workerObjectIdType)`

```
Method getID = workerObjectTypeRef.getDeclaredMethod("getID");
Object id = getID.invoke(workerObjectType);
Class idRef = id.getClass();
Method add = idRef.getDeclaredMethod("add", workerObjectIDTypeRef);
add.invoke(id, workerObjectIDType);
```